# Restore root.disk files (or boot in low-graphics mode)

Tags: windows, wubi, login, restore

Once something bad happend and my ubuntu has falled down. After this when booting i have message "You are in low-graphics mode now, your screen and other devices can't be detected automaticly. You have to configure it manually", then i press enter key and get next window where 4 options like "Log in low-graphics mode" etc. and nothing happends and nothing works. All i can do is shut down the system. No mouse, no keyboard works (i guess).

So i can't boot. Actually i need files from my home directory, it's only reason stops me to reinstall ubuntu.

How can i log in or get files from root.disk (i also have windows 7 on my computer)

Comment: Seems like i should boot from live cd and mount disk from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [ext2read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/) from Windows (read only).

If you are trying to repair it you can do the following:

1. Run `chkdsk /f` from Windows first. If it's the `C:` drive you'll need to reboot to complete the check.
2. If you have a live CD, I'd recommend trying to repair first by `fsck`ing the root.disk (see the [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_access_my_Wubi_install_and_repair_my_install_if_it_won.27t_boot.3F) for help). This sounds like what is required based on your description, but I'd still run `chkdsk` first.
3. If both those fail, then you can fall back to the backup and reinstall. A normal dual boot is best.

One other thing you can look for is low space... that can cause weird issues.